# Product not showing in frontside

Tags: magento2, product, upgrade, magento2.4

I have updated Magento version 2.3.5-p1 to Magento 2.4.0 but after upgrade products not showing in front side.

I have reset index also it's showing valid

[image]

I've tried the following things in an attempt to fix it, but none of them helped:

- Re-indexing Checking Visibility is set to Catalog & Search for all
  products
- Checking Status is set to Enabled for all products
- Checking   Inventory is greater than 0 and status is set to 'In Stock' for all
  products Checking Website is set to base for all products
- Flushing all Caches
- Switching to default Luma theme to see if it was a theme bug (didn't work)
- Disable All 3rd Party plugin.
- In Product collection, it's showing 0 counts but when I run collection query in DB then products come in result
- Source assigned to the website

Comment: Do you see data in elasticsearch? you can try querying elasticsearch directly also to see if there is anything in there

Comment: can you give me some example @arif

Answer (score 0):

try to check product visibility , it should be catalog, search.
if you are looking on product list page you should attach your products to the category.
If you are lookig on serach check products on your search engine.

Another way try to check if your product pag is accessible by url /catalog/product/view/id/{product_id}

last thing check your product attribute set.

Hope that helps you.